# Redirecting rabbitmq-server log messages to syslog

Tags: syslog, rabbitmq

I have a CentOS machine running rabbitmq-server v2.2.0-1.el5, and rabbitmq is outputting it's log messages to various files under /var/log/rabbitmq.

If there anyway to configure rabbitmq to tell it to redirect its messages to syslog instead ?

Comment: That is a very old version of RabbitMQ that has lots of bugs which have since been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way for RabbitMQ to log directly to syslog. But you could process the log files RabbitMQ generates and write them to syslog, e. g. with [rsyslog's imfile module](http://rsyslog.com/doc/imfile.html).

Comment: The imfile module is just what I was looking for.  Thanks.